# Работа с файлами, вопрос о перезаписи

Tags: c++, файловый-ввод-вывод

Имеется текстовый файл, в который записываются значения из массива типа int. Запись происходит таким образом:

```
string filename;
cout << "Введите путь к файлу: ";
cin >> filename;

ofstream infile(filename);

if (!infile.is_open()) // если файл небыл открыт
{
    cout << "Файл не может быть открыт или создан\n";
}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        infile << array[i] << ' ';
        {
            infile << endl;
        }

    }
    cout << "Записано." << endl;
    infile.close();
}
```

Необходимо выполнить проверку на то, есть ли в файле уже записи, и если есть выдать сообщение с вопросом о перезаписи, используя `ofstream` все данные из него удаляются, либо файл создается чистым (так скажем с нуля). Как решить данную проблему не знаю, подтолкните к решению.

Comment: Вначале вычитывать весь файл с помощью ifstream, анализировать его записи и если надо потом перезаписать весь файл через ofstream. Это если файл не большой по своей природе, если большой и с бинарной структурой тогда нужно егео перезаписывать частями или дописывать в конец.

Comment: Для \*nix-ов см. [man 2 stat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) (в винде наверняка тоже есть аналог)

Comment: @Arty OneSoul, а без навязывания таких костылей, как счет через ifstream обойтись никак? Файл "относительно" небольшой.

Comment: fstat() может сказать пустой файл (размер 0) или нет. Правда, с ним есть нюансы в 32 битной винде под 32- и 64-битную "версии" файлов (в смысле, для очень больших). Если же нужно еще анализировать сожержимое - от этой ли программы тот файл или нет... ну, можно в первых паре байтов поместить какой-нибудь идентификатор (кроме своего расширения файла)... чтобы не пытаться читать весь файл.

Answer (score 0):

Если файл существует (его можно открыть) - спросить о перезаписи. Если ответ - перезаписывать, открыть файл в режиме по умолчанию (с перезаписью с нулевого размера). Если нет - открыть в режиме добавления (`ios::ate`).

Можно сразу открыть в режиме дозаписи, и если надо перезаписать, становиться в начало и писать. Но здесь есть опасный момент - может, придется записать меньше, чем в файле уже есть, и получится ерунда - вначале новые данные, а дальше - нестёртые старые.

Comment: Я не понял - перезаписать - это и есть создать новый!

Answer (score 0):

- `is_open` - проверка открывается-ли файл
- `read` , `good` - есть-ли хоть один байт в файле
- `std::ios::trunc` - флаг всё стереть
- `std::ios::app` - флаг дописать в конец

пример :

```
// g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++11 appendfile.cpp -o appendfile
# include <string>
using std::string;
# include <iostream>
using std::cout ;
using std::cin ;
# include <fstream>
using std::ifstream ;
using std::ofstream ;
int main(){
  string filename;
  cout << "Введите путь к файлу: ";
  cin >> filename;
  bool filenotempty ;
  { ifstream f(filename.c_str());
    if (f.is_open()) {
      char c ;
      f.read(&c,1);
      filenotempty = f.good();
      f.close(); } }
  bool fileerase = false ;
  if ( filenotempty ) {
    cout << "Файл содержит данные, стереть их ? (Yes/No)";
    string answer ;
    cin >> answer ;
    fileerase = (answer [0] == 'Y') ; }
  ofstream  ofile ;
  ofile.open ( filename ,
    filenotempty ?
      ( fileerase ? std::ios::trunc : std::ios::app ) :
      std::ios::out ) ;
  ofile << "запись" << std::endl;
  ofile.close();
}
```